# Huge delay in calling disconnect callback of an inactive publisher

Tags: ros, roscpp, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Consider the following example:

`#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

void connectCallback(const ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher&)
{
  ROS_INFO("connectCallback");
}

void disconnectCallback(const ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher&)
{
  ROS_INFO("disconnectCallback");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "test_node");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::String>("talk", 1, &connectCallback, &disconnectCallback);
  ros::Rate r(1);
  while (nh.ok())
  {
    ROS_INFO("Number of subscribers: %zu", pub.getNumSubscribers());
    ros::spinOnce();
    r.sleep();
  }
  return 0;
}`

When subscribing using `rostopic echo /talk`, `connectCallback` is called immediately. However, when shutting down the `rostopic` process, the reported number of subscribers is still 1 until `disconnectCallback` gets called about one minute later. Why? Is there any way to shorten this timeout?
When the publisher is active (i.e. publishing something in the loop), `disconnectCallback` is called immediately.

EDIT

Here is another subscriber (different from `rostopic`) that I used for testing with the same result:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

void callback(const std_msgs::StringConstPtr& msg)
{
  std::cout << msg->data << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "subscriber");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("talk", 1, &callback);

  ros::Time start_time = ros::Time::now();
  while (ros::ok() && (ros::Time::now() - start_time).toSec() < 10)
  {
    ros::spinOnce();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12673/huge-delay-in-calling-disconnect-callback-of-an-inactive-publisher/) by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1924 on 2012-01-17

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2012-01-18**:
@Lorenz: I tried that already, I'll edit the question to clarify this.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-01-17**:
I would guess that the rostopic process does not shutdown correctly and after a minute, your node notices that the socket is invalid. I would write a simple roscpp node that subscribes, stays connected for a while and then shuts down. If that works, you know it's rostopic's fault.

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2012-01-17**:
I just tried using a self-made subscriber, same result.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-01-17**:
One guess would be that shutting down rostopic doesn't properly close the connection (although it should), so only when you try to publish the node realizes it's disconnected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is ticketed at https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3403. There I wrote:

> I've noticed this issue with
> unsubscribe callbacks too. However,
> it's not true that they're never
> called; they *do* get called exactly
> 60s after you subscribe.
>
> In practice this shouldn't normally be
> an issue. In each nodelet we use
> connect callbacks to control whether
> it hooks into a data source (camera or
> ROS topic). As long as it's getting
> data, it publishes some processed
> output. So if all subscribers to the
> output unsubscribe, the next call to
> publish() triggers the disconnect
> callback, which unhooks from the data
> source. So as long as you're streaming
> data, disconnects will be timely.
>
> It's still annoying and can cause odd
> behavior in practice - e.g. if the
> register nodelet doesn't get the tf
> data it needs, it can't publish(), so
> it takes the full 60s to disconnect.
> So I'd like to see this fixed, or at
> least know why it happens.

Generally this hasn't been an issue for us - if we need the disconnect callback called immediately, it's because we're shutting down a publisher that's continuously spewing data. Do you have a use case where you require a timely disconnect callback for an inactive publisher?

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2012-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2012-01-18**:
Thanks Patrick, I'll mark your answer as accepted as the solution will come up in ticket 3403. Use case: a lazy node that subscribes to inputs if its output is needed and publishes dependent on the input data (object found). So if the object disappears, publish is not called. Similar to your tf ex.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have updated Issue 3403 with a comment. Without having delved deep into the internals of roscpp, Maybe the reported issue might have something to do with the time a closed socket spends in the TIME_WAIT state, which is configured by the **tcp_fin_timeout** parameter, that defaults to 60s:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout
60
```

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2012-01-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2